# JavaScript Puppeteer Scraping a Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape HTML data from a variable that holds HTML data. You can see my annotations, they are marked with " << ".
Unfortunately, `evaluate` only works on a page on not in a `div`. Could someone tell me how I could scrape information from a variable containing HTML?

Are there perhaps other methods of scraping?

I tried this in the `forEach` loop as well, but this resulted in the first `mealname` of the original document.

```
let mealName = htmlOfOneProduct.document.querySelector("div.meal__description-texts.js-meal-description-text > span > span").innerText;
```

My code with notes:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(" "); << Meal website
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let results = [];
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('div.meal__wrapper'); << Gets all the meals from a page
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    let htmlOfOneProduct = item.innerHTML; << Gets the HTML of each meal

                    let mealName = htmlOfOne.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('meal-name').textContent); << Not working, should get the meal-name from the div.

                    results.push({
                        mealName: mealName
                    });
                });
                return results;
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did not provide the site URL, I cannot check my proposal, sorry.

`item.innerHTML` returns a string which has no `evaluate()` method. Try this simpler way:

```js
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    let mealName = item.querySelector('meal-name').textContent;
                    results.push({
                        mealName: mealName
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Using your code, node returns the following: "Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
"

Comment: This works! Thanks! let mealName = item.querySelector('span.meal-name').innerText;

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps   `let htmlOfOneProduct = item.innerHTML; << Gets the HTML of each meal` it's not necessary.

If you only need the content of something you could directly do `item.innerText` or `item.name` or any other propriety of the element.

In the end something like this should be possible:

```
items.forEach((item) => {    
   let mealName = item.querySelector('meal-name').innerText
   results.push({
        mealName: mealName
   });
});
```

Comment: This worked! "                    let mealName = item.querySelector('span.meal-name').innerText;
"

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine your CSS selectors and use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to simplify scraping the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) of the elements:

```
let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.meal__wrapper span.meal-name'), e => ({
    mealName: e.innerText,
  });
});
```